# Can a PVC sprinkler pipe that is encased in concrete have restricted preasure due to the concrete?

Tags: pipe, pvc

A metal post was installed  in concrete for a fence. There is an existing PVC pipe that controls the sprinkler  that is now in-cased in the concrete that was poured for the post.

Can the concrete that was poured cause a restriction in the flow of water?

If so what can be used to prevent that from happening? What could have happened if I had full pressure before the concrete was poured and now I have very little after it was poured?

Comment: Is that the only place the pressure is lower? A lot of folks are watering this time of year...

Comment: yes that is the other zones work fine.  this zone worked fine before the concrete was poured.

Answer (score 2):

If the pipe was collapsed it could create an issue but normally it will have no effect on the flow pvc pipe is tough enough not to collapse even with several feet of concrete over it.

Comment: Hopefully they didn't damage the pipe when digging the hole.+1

Answer (score 2):

Concrete poured over PVC pipe will not collapse it. If the zone worked before the concrete was poured but has little pressure now, chances are the pipe was damaged when the concrete was poured, either by it being shoveled in the hole or it being compacted to remove air pockets. It's not uncommon to use a 2x4 to compact concrete while it's being poured and this action could have damaged the pipe. At this point all you can do is install some new PVC around the fence post and abandon the damaged section.